# Angular - How to set selected values for a mat-select from a datasource of a dynamic sized table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am setting up a mat-table that shows some values from a datasource and has a mat-select with multiple select in each row. The datasource for the table is an array of objects("CarManufacturer"), that holds another array of objects("Brand"). In the mat-select I show a complete list of all "Brands".

At the moment I cant de-/select those "Brands". They are marked as selected or not. I am not able to change this.

I have created a function that returns an array of number(ids of brands), which feeds [value] of mat-select. That marks brands in the dropdown which are in the array of CarManufactors, but I cannot select anything in the dropdown.

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skrrhb

I expect that I can change the values of the dropdown. At the moment I cannot de-/select the values.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you please send the code too? That link only has the demo app

Comment: Updated the stackblitz url to the editor path.

Comment: Hmm.. You should be using 2 way binding instead. The reason why the select option boxes cant be 'deselected' is because you have binded each of them to the `getArray()` method, which has already set the values.

Comment: I tried using [(ngModel)]. Didnt get it to work because I feel I need that getArray() method. Any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `<mat-select [value]="getArray(element.brands)" multiple>` is always returning the same value no matter what.

One solution would be to add an brandSelected in the brand interface and store the values there:

```
export interface CarManufacturer {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  brands: Brand[];
  brandsSelected?: number[]; 
}
```

And then apply a two way data binding in the  mat-select like this:

```
   <mat-select [(value)]="element.brandSelected" multiple>
```

**You can see the working example here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujirgb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html